# Как разослать запланированные сообщения пользователям ТГ бота?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Я хочу сделать ТГ бота для изучения иностранных слов, и мне нужно, чтобы бот на aiogram 2.25.1 отправлял определённому пользователю со своим прогрессом изучения слов слово и его перевод каждый час с 9:00 до 21:00 по московскому времени без моего вмешательства как админа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно оптимально и красиво реализовать.
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Проверяйте дату каждый час, если прошёл уже час, тогда отправляйте прогресс и обнуляйте дату (ну или ставьте на текущую, зависит от реализации проверки).

Comment: @ΝNL993 если бы я более-менее знал, как это реализовать, я бы это сделал уже давно

Comment: Ну и это на python надо сделать, а не на javascript